# Non-reversible MCMC based on diffusion dynamics

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

Given that the current sample location is $x\in[0,1)^d$, I would like to take the next sample $y$ as $$y=x+b(x)\Delta t+\sigma(x)\sqrt{\Delta t}\xi\;;\;\;\;\xi\sim\mathcal N_{0,\:I_d}\tag1$$ for some suitably chosen $\Delta t$, $b$ and $\sigma$. I will wrap $y$ around to stay in $[0,1)^d$; i.e. I effectively replace $y$ by $\iota(y)$, where $$\iota:\mathbb R^d\to[0,1)^d\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x-\lfloor x\rfloor.$$ From time to time (there are multiple ways to do that) I draw $y$ from the uniform distribution on $[0,1)^d$ instead to not get stuck.

So, I could use this as a proposal for a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm; but I'm not forced to do so. Maybe a non-reversible method would be more suitable. There are two related approaches: [Non-reversible Metropolis-Hastings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.8087) and [Non-reversible guided Metropolis-Hastings kernel](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Non-reversible-guided-Metropolis-Hastings-kernel-Kamatani-Song/b627cdc9984d9dd43a920444042a7d7bc40a3561), but neither of them seems to be immediately applicable for my idea.

The idea behind $(1)$ is to select $\sigma(x)$ so that it is smaller, where there target density $p$ is large. And $b(x)$ should move the sample in a direction where $p$ is increasing. However, the problem with this is that my $p$ is not differentiable. So, I cannot take $b(x)=\nabla p(x)$ for example.

I'm also willing to use a continuous-time MCMC sampler. But, for example, the diffusion corresponding to $(1)$ the generator domain usually consists of differentiable functions as well and continuous-time approaches usually require the target density to belong to the domain (of the adjoint) of the generator ...